# Add a input text next to the selected item in a select list

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-chosen

This portion of code is used to create a select list:

Can we add an input field at the highlighted area?

```html
<select id="second" data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" multiple style="width:350px;" tabindex="4">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="United States">United States</option>
  <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
  <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
  <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
  <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
  <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
  <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<button class="btn">Reset</button>
```

[image]

Comment: No! you have to create a custom dropdown or if you are using bootstrap you can use the dropdown and add input fields into the elements. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/

Comment: It is not allowed to have an input field inside a `select` element. You would have to hack something together that adds the input and positions it appropriately. You can look at how similar solutions are implemented, e.g. in extjs.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] - it looks like you are using [chosen](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/chosen) so please include relevant frameworks and plugins

Comment: you could listen to changes on the select and display absolute position text fields when an option is selected

Comment: @RecencyEffect He is using a plugin that rewrites the select completely